# Powershell Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation Error

Tags: powershell

I'm getting IP address of vShpere VM by using this command:

```
$VMIPAddress = (Get-VM -Name $VMName).Guest.IPAddress | Select-Object -First 1
```

and I'm trying to add DHCP reservation by using this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mdc1.ad.morphisec.com -ScriptBlock{ 
Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 -IPAddress $VMIPAddress -ClientId $VMMacAddress -Description $VMname
}
```

But I'm getting this error all the time:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'IPAddress'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation
+ PSComputerName        : mdc1.ad.morphisec.com
```

I understand this is happening because the variable $VMIPAddress is string...

```
$VMIPAddress.GetType().name 

String
```

**But how can I convert it to Integer/IPaddress and pass it to the** *Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation* **command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass variables to a session in another computer with Invoke-Command you need to use the *using* prefix to the variable name. Such as:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mdc1.ad.morphisec.com -ScriptBlock{ 
    Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 -IPAddress $using:VMIPAddress -ClientId $using:VMMacAddress -Description $using:VMname
}
```

As for a reference read the [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2) conceptual help section.

Answer (score 1):

It's a variable scope issue:
`$VMIPAddress = (Get-VM -Name $VMName).Guest.IPAddress | Select-Object -First 1`
is creating a local variable, so it's not recognized by the `-Scriptblock` parameter for `Invoke-Command`, because it has its own scope. You need to send it to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Comment: That's true but a bit dated. Since PowerShell 3.0 we use the 'using' prefix.

Comment: Always more than one way to write a script.